# Gulp, browser sync does not work with angularjs ng-view

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browser-sync

I am trying to set up a project using gulp and browser sync with angularjs. I cannot get browser sync to work correctly when I use the ng-view tag in my index.html file. This is the error I get in my browser console when I run browser sync: 
    `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data1457531805746' of null` 
coming from `browser-sync-client.2.11.1.js:204` It works as expected, page loads fine, when ng-view/ngRoute is not used.

These are my files:
./gulpfile.js

```
// Spin up a server
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.use(spa({
  selector: "[ng-app]" //Only needed for angular apps
  }));

  browserSync.init({
    port: 8080,
    server: {
      baseDir: path.src
    }
  })
});

 // Watch for changes in files
 gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], function() {
    // Watch .js files -- removed for brevity
  });
 // Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

./app/controllers/controllers.js
    'use strict';

```
/* Controllers */

var dc4SearchControllers = angular.module('dc4SearchControllers', []);

dc4SearchControllers.controller('CompanySearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http){
    $scope.test = 'Hello, world!';
}]);
```

./app/index.html

```
<html ng-app="dc4SearchApp">
<head>
  <link href="/bower_components/webui-core/dist/webui-core.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="/bower_components/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/webui-core/dist/webui-core.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-view>

</body>
</html>
```

./app/app.js
    'use strict';

```
/* App Module */

var dc4SearchApp = angular.module('dc4SearchApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'dc4SearchControllers'
]);

dc4SearchApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/company-search', {
        templateUrl: 'views/company-search.html',
        controller: 'CompanySearchCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/company-search'
      });
  }]);
```

./app/views/company-search.html

```
<div ng-controller="CompanySearchCtrl">
  <a href="#" class="button confirm">{{test}}</a>
  <div class="spinner spin"> </div>
</div>
```

I am hoping this is just something silly and easy that I am over looking and haven't tried yet! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the same error for which I fixed it by placing the angular script before the jQuery scipt tag in my index.html file. No idea why this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Browsersync works by injecting an asynchronous script tag right after the body tag during initial request. In order for this to work properly the body tag must be present. Alternatively you can provide a custom rule for the snippet using snippetOptions"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync

It seems Browsersync is reloading the body tag. Have you tried moving the ng-view to another child div ?

Comment: Wow, I had not tried that but it seems to work! Something silly and easy I had not tried yet. Thanks for the help!